# DataGrid displaying content value of 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I'm having an issue with one of my DataGrids which is leaving me at a loss as I've always done it this way, and it's always worked...

My DataTable is implemented like this:

```
MyDataSets.Cash_TableData cashTable = new MyDataSets.Cash_TableData();
```

I then populate it with some data via:

```
cashTable = cashTableAdapter.GetDataByName(PersonsName);
```

This all works fine.

I have a DataGrid with the following:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,354,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="282" Width="695" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

And I populate the DataGrid with...

```
dataGrid.DataContext = cashTable.DefaultView;
```

However, when I do this every column displays the correct data except column 8 which says "System.Data.DataRowView".

I did a Console.WriteLine with each item in the DataTable at column 8 and it all came out correctly.

Any ideas whats needed to make column 8 display correctly? column type is string.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The cash table is now below. Some column names changed for privacy reasons...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cash Table] (
    [Id]                 INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Gender]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DOB]                DATE           NOT NULL,
    [Address]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Address_Two]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Person_ID]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Transaction_Date]   DATE           NOT NULL,
    [Item]              NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('Not recorded') NOT NULL,
    [xxx]   NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('Not recorded') NULL,
    [Amount]             FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
    [xxx]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [xxx]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [xxx] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [xxx]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [xxx]         BIT            NOT NULL,
    [xxx]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [xxx]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation of the Cash_TableData?

Comment: Does column 8 have a name? Check [THIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c05b0ae2-86c5-4b14-9578-8e8f6d2e3175/datagrid-cell-has-systemdatadatarowview-as-a-value?forum=wpf).

Comment: Column 8 does have a name, 'Item'.

Comment: The problem is with your `DataTable`, which you don't show, not your DDL.

Comment: Looks like the issues is with column name 'item'.

Comment: I tried you code from what you supplied and it worked fine for me. Try posting the entire code and xaml, maybe we will notice something else.
My implementation was:
var table = new MyDataSet.Cash_TableDataTable();
            var adapter = new MyDataSetTableAdapters.Cash_TableTableAdapter();
            adapter.Fill(table);

            dataGrid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this thread on the MSDN forums:

**DataGrid cell has 'System.Data.DataRowView' as a value:** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c05b0ae2-86c5-4b14-9578-8e8f6d2e3175/datagrid-cell-has-systemdatadatarowview-as-a-value?forum=wpf

Make sure that the name of the column doesn't contain a space. For example, this will make the cell value displayed as  "System.Data.DataRowView":

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(" ") { });
dt.Rows.Add("1");
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

This works:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("") { });
```

And this results in a blank cell (note the trailing space in the column name):

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name ") { });
```

So try to set the name of column 8 (or whatever the index of your column is) to a valid name without a space:

```
cashTable.Columns[0].ColumnName = "unique";
dataGrid.DataContext = cashTable.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Control this 3 cases, and I think that column is ComboBox, DropDownlist or something like this with Value property

> 1) Column(or column controls) related field name not assigned
>
> 2) Column(or column controls) related field name may be wrong
>
> 3) Column(or column controls) related field name has whitespaces